# akka actor failure affect on the os process

Tags: akka

If say the code that my actor uses (a code I have no control over) throws an unhandled exception, could that result into the whole actor system process to crash or each actor is running in some kind of special container?

To clarify more, in my use case, I want each actor to load (at run time) some user written code/lib and call some interface methods on them. These libs maybe buggy and can potentially result in my actor system os process to die or halt or something like that. I mean what if the code that actor calls does something that halt (like accessing a remote resource by a buggy client or a dead loop) or even call Enviroment.exit() or something of bad nature.

I mean if my requirement is to allow each actor to load code that I do not have control over, how can I guard my actor system against them? Do I even have to do this?

One way that I can think the whole actor system OS process guard itself against these third party code is to run each actor inside some kind of a container or event have one actor system per actor on the local machine that my actor controls? Do I have to go this far or akka already takes care of this for me and any failure at actor level would not jeopardize the whole actor system and its process??

Comment: Have you read: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/general/supervision.html

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear enough. I just update it!

Answer (score 0):

If the JVM process dies, the JVM process dies. You get around that by using Akka Cluster so you can observe and react to node failures.